# How to avoid entering password for new Rails app?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, macos

After I run `rails new myapp`, it downloads gems and then at `run bundle install`, I always get prompted to enter in my system password.

Is there a way to set the password so I don't have to keep entering it in?

Comment: # you can try  install gem with the specified path  =>                                                    
bundle install --path vendor/bundle

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Background info

Why do you have to enter the password in the first place? Because by default bundler will install gems in a system wide location, such as `/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/...`. These gems can be used by every user on your pc.

Because it is a shared location, it is usually only writeable by root and therefore you have to enter your password to gain root privileges.

Where are your gems stored? Find out by using `bundle show <gem>` for a specific gem, for example `rake`, which in my case says:

```
bundle show rake
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/rake-10.4.2
```

### Solution

#### a) Change owner of directory

Either make this directory writeable for you. But this is no good practise, because system folders should not be writeable for a normal user. In case you are the only user it still might be OK - then you can simply change the owner of this directory to be you:

```
sudo chown -R `whoami` /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/
```

Now you are the owner and can change files inside without the need of any password.

#### b) Install gems locally inside project dir

Or you can install all gems locally inside your project dir using the `--path` option of bundler. It is a convention that those gems are normally installed in `vendor/bundle`, so you use this command (you can use any path you want):

```
bundle install --path vendor/bundle
```

(When you do `bundle update` next time, you can omit the `--path` option, because it is saved in the `.bundle` folder of your project.)

You should add the `vendor/bundle` folder to your `.gitignore` (or whatever vcs you are using) to not have it checked in.

Since you write inside a directory you own, you do not have to enter a password. The downside of this is that gems will be duplicated in every project folder if you have multiple projects using the same gems. For a multi user system this is the correct way. But if you are the only one using the machine, variant a) definitely helps to save space and install time.

I'm using variant a) on my own development machine and variant b) on the deployment machine.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like a permissions issue. Try `chmod a+w /path/to/bundler`